# oil in my radiator

Tags: coolant

I have a 95 f150. pretty much everything is original on it. I now have oil in my radiator but. looks like thick poo when I took the cap off. but when I checked my oil other than being a quart low the oil is clean. just seeing what it could be.

Comment: could be a blown head gasket

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the head gasket A blown head gasket may cause a number of different symptoms. Coolant in the engine oil, an engine misfire or oil leaking from the engine could all be a symptom. Each of these symptoms could also have other causes and an actual blown head gasket may show none of the above symptoms. Hope this helped ?